# Angular 1: Last checkbox doesn't stay checked after page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I am saving all data into localStorage. When a checkbox is checked function is called to change items state. It works fine. However after page refresh, last checked item gets unchecked (or if it was unchecked, it gets checked) while others are working just fine. Why does that 1 last action gets ignored after page is refreshed?

Here is codepen: http://codepen.io/kunokdev/pen/vGeEoY?editors=1010

(add few items and click on "click me" for all of them and then refresh page, last action will be ignored)

The view:

```
<div ng-app="TaskApp" ng-controller="ToDoCtrl">
  <form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="toDoItem">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="addToDoItem()">
  </form>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <div
        ng-repeat="item in toDoItems |
                   orderBy: 'createdAt'
                   track by item.createdAt">
        <b>Content:</b> {{item.content}} <br>
        <b>Completed?</b> {{item.completed}}
        <md-checkbox ng-model="item.completed" ng-click="toggleToDoItem(item.completed)" aria-label="todo-checkbox">
          CLICK ME
        </md-checkbox>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
var ls = {};

ls.get = function(key) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
};

// sets or updates a value for a key
ls.set = function(key, val) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(val));
};

// returns true if value is set, else false
ls.isSet = function(key) {
    var val = ls.get(key);
    return ( null === val || 'undefined' === typeof val) ? false : true;
};

// removes a set item
ls.remove = function(key) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key)
};


var TaskApp = angular.module('TaskApp', [
  'ngMaterial',
  'taskAppControllers'
]);

var taskAppControllers = angular.module('taskAppControllers',[]);

taskAppControllers.controller('ToDoCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope){
    //
    loadToDoItems = function(){
      var data = ls.get("toDoData");
      if (data == null) data = [];
      return data;
    };
    //
    $scope.toDoItems = loadToDoItems();
    //
    $scope.addToDoItem = function(){
      var toDoItems = $scope.toDoItems;
      var newToDoItem = {
        "content" : $scope.toDoItem,
        "createdAt" : Date.now(),
        "completed" : false
      }
      toDoItems.push(newToDoItem);
      ls.set("toDoData", toDoItems);
      $scope.toDoItem = "";
    };
    //
    $scope.toggleToDoItem = function(item){
      console.log('test');
      var toDoItems = $scope.toDoItems;
      for (var i = 0; i < toDoItems.length; i++)
        if (toDoItems[i].createdAt === item){
          if (toDoItems[i].completed == true)
            toDoItems[i].completed = false;
          else
            toDoItems[i].completed = true;
        }
      ls.set('toDoData', toDoItems);
    };
    //
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`md-checkbox` is designed to toggle whatever you put in `ng-model` so with your code, `md-checkbox` was toggling the `completed` property and then you were changing it back again in your `$scope.toggleToDoItem` function. Why this worked for all the items except the last clicked I am unsure.

So I changed the `ng-click` to only save the items to local storage and still got the same problem which leads to me believe the problem is caused by using `ng-click` on an `md-checkbox`.

```
 <md-checkbox ng-model="item.completed" ng-click="saveToLocalStorage()" aria-label="todo-checkbox">
    CLICK ME
 </md-checkbox>

$scope.saveToLocalStorage = function() {
  ls.set('toDoData', $scope.toDoItems);
};
```

So I removed the `ng-click` and set up a watch on `$scope.toDoItems`.

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="item.completed" aria-label="todo-checkbox">

$scope.$watch("toDoItems", function() {
  ls.set("toDoData", $scope.toDoItems);
}, true);
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Jaydo/pen/XdemmW?editors=1010)

**-- EDIT --**

Just read the documentation and feel like an idiot, you should use `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`. From the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdCheckbox)  regarding `ng-change`:

> Angular expression to be executed when input changes due to user interaction with the input element.

That being said, the above about not needing to toggle the `completed` property yourself still stands.

Comment: And once more, Rintarō Okabe saves the day!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing item.completed (in the HTML) to your toggleToDoItem(item) method. In your array loop, you then compare the item.Created field to the item.completed parameter.  This is comparing a Date type to a Bool. How is that supposed to work?